# Start new job with quartz in Java

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I would like understand how to a job, start new job after of finished with quartz in java.

My Jobs Bean:

```
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDownload() {

    JobDetailFactoryBean j = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    j.setJobClass(DownloadJob.class);
    j.setName("jobDownload");
    j.setGroup("group1");
    return j;
}


@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobRegex() {

    JobDetailFactoryBean j = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    j.setJobClass(RegexJob.class);
    j.setName("jobRegex");
    j.setGroup("group1");
    return j;
}
```

My Trigger Bean:

```
@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean triggerDownload() {

    CronTriggerFactoryBean cron = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    cron.setName("triggerDownload");
    cron.setGroup("group1");
    cron.setCronExpression("0 15 17 * * ?");
    cron.setJobDetail(jobConfiguration.jobDownload().getObject());

    return cron;
}
```

My Scheduler:

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean sched() {

    SchedulerFactoryBean sched = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

    try {


        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        sched.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

        // Agendando execução das triggers
        sched.setTriggers(triggerConfiguration.triggerDownload()
                .getObject());

        sched.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sched;
}
```

My Job Executer:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DownloadJob implements Job {

@Autowired
private RegexService service;


@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext j) throws JobExecutionException {

    try {

        DownloadService t = new DownloadService();
        File file = t
                .fazerDownload(
                        "nameFile",
                        "urlName");
        service.aplicaTreeRegex(3L, file, 789L);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I would like `jobDownload` to start `jobRegex` after finish. How to do that?

Comment: This looks like a code dump without a lot of research effort.

Comment: Solved with [JobListener](https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/JobListeners)

Comment: Then you ought to post an answer to the question explaining the solution--you might help future users